# how do you trim the result of mongodb's $arrayElemAt when it has extra white space?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

this is code i have:

```
$addFields: {
    category: {
        // $product_categories => ['  test ', 'foo']
        $arrayElemAt: ['$product_categories', 0] 
    },
}
```

the 'category' field will be assign to '  test ', from the database,
from which i want to trim the extra space, front and back,
the result should be 'test' without the extra space,
is this possible? how to do it?? thanks

Comment: What is your MongoDB version?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MongoDB version > 4.0, you can use [`$trim`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/trim/#trim-aggregation) operator. So try this:

```js
$addFields: {
  category: {
    // $product_categories => ['  test ', 'foo']
    $trim: {
      input: { $arrayElemAt: ['$product_categories', 0] }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you..it work..i missed the bracket several times, resulting syntax error at first